# Why does <body onload="fn();"> use a function call, but window.onload=fn; use a handler function?

Tags: javascript

I've read about the technical differences such as which option waits for the appropriate elements to load, but for most cases I understand that they both serve a similar purpose.

I'd like to know about the rationale behind needing to call the function (say, initialize();) when using  but only using the function name if writing window.onload=myFunction. (MDN calls it a handler function). Here, I'm referring to the difference being the missing parentheses.

Is there an advantage to either approach? A technical reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between HTML markup and the Document Object Model that Javascript uses.  When you run:

```
window.onload = fn;
```

That is setting the property "onload" to that function object, which is to handle the event.  If on the other hand, you wrote:

```
window.onload = fn();
```

that would execute fn immediately, and set the onload property to whatever value the function returns (which could also work, if the function fn returned another function).

Answer (score 2):

The `onload` attribute contains a string of Javascript code to execute.
It doesn't need to be a function call; it can be arbitrary statements.

The `onload` property just holds a function.

Comment: Yes; that's an HTML attribute.